# Vertical Headings table Angular material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

in this example,
( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtyoyq?file=src/app/app.component.ts ),
we have basic table, but in my case I want to make this table like this :

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>No.</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Hydrogen</td>
    <td>Helium</td>
    <td>Lithium</td>
    <td>Beryllium</td>
            
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <td>1.0079</td>
    <td>4.0026</td>
    <td>6.941</td>
    <td>9.0122</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Symbol</th>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>He</td>
    <td>Li</td>
    <td>Be</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use invert the table in an `ngOnInit()` method in the class to give the required data structure and then iterate over the column list in the HTML to give the required columns. Below is an example:

**Html File:**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="displayData" class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="showTable">

  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ column }} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[column] }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

**TS File:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample implements OnInit {
  inputColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  inputData = ELEMENT_DATA;

  displayColumns: string[];
  displayData: any[];
  showTable: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayColumns = this.inputData.map(x => x.position.toString());
    this.displayData = this.inputColumns.map(x => this.formatInputRow(x));

    console.log(this.displayColumns);
    console.log(this.displayData);

    this.showTable = true;
  }

  formatInputRow(row) {
    const output = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < this.inputData.length; ++i) {
      output[this.inputData[i].position] = this.inputData[i][row];
    }

    return output;
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];
```

***Working Example*** **[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6dvzc-jjqdpk?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)**

Comment: Hello Mr Sumit, thank you for help ,
i do it with other methode like this : 
<table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody *ngFor="let item of displayedColumns">
                <tr >
                  <th scope="row">{{item}}</th>
                  <td *ngFor="let data of KPIDataSource "
                  class="DateRow"
                  >

Comment: sorry for the firsts comment  I'm newbie stack overflow thank you for help ,
i do this 
<table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody *ngFor="let item of displayedColumns">
                <tr >
//the headers row
                  <th scope="row">{{item}}</th>
//body 
                  <td *ngFor="let data of DataSource "
class="DateRow" >
{{data}}
</td>
</tr> 
but the problem is when I want to style my table like the first or the third row with background color red, in my case I cannot style mu table because I have one td, do you have any idea?

Comment: `tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: red; }`put this in your css.

Comment: He makes all <tr> red, because we have one <tr>

Comment: try with `<td>` then

Comment: its work with tbody ^-^ ty

Answer (score 0):

Need to override styles of angular material, Apply styles in global file so it can override it. If you apply in component it would not work due to view encapsulation.
Note: Never use ng-deep in any file.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it with ng-container... , can you help me